Read from local path in Apache druid
I am currently working with Apache Druid and encountering an issue while attempting to read files from local paths. Specifically, when I try to access files located in a local directory, I receive an error message indicating that there are no files in /opt/druid and the path I have added. I suspect this issue might be related to the need to bind the /opt/druid directory to a corresponding local path on my system. Could you please guide me on how to properly configure this binding?
docker-compose.yml
version: "2.2"

volumes:
  metadata_data: {}
  middle_var: {}
  historical_var: {}
  broker_var: {}
  coordinator_var: {}
  router_var: {}
  druid_shared: {}


services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - metadata_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=FoolishPassword
      - POSTGRES_USER=druid
      - POSTGRES_DB=druid

  # Need 3.5 or later for container nodes
  zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeeper
    image: zookeeper:3.5.10
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      - ZOO_MY_ID=1

  coordinator:
    image: apache/druid:29.0.1
    container_name: coordinator
    volumes:
      - druid_shared:/opt/shared
      - coordinator_var:/opt/druid/var
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    command:
      - coordinator
    env_file:
      - environment

  broker:
    image: apache/druid:29.0.1
    container_name: broker
    volumes:
      - broker_var:/opt/druid/var
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - postgres
      - coordinator
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    command:
      - broker
    env_file:
      - environment

  historical:
    image: apache/druid:29.0.1
    container_name: historical
    volumes:
      - druid_shared:/opt/shared
    depends_on: 
      - zookeeper
      - postgres
      - coordinator
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    command:
      - historical
    env_file:
      - environment

  middlemanager:
    image: apache/druid:29.0.1
    container_name: middlemanager
    volumes:
      - druid_shared:/opt/shared
      - middle_var:/opt/druid/var
    depends_on: 
      - zookeeper
      - postgres
      - coordinator
    ports:
      - "8091:8091"
      - "8100-8105:8100-8105"
    command:
      - middleManager
    env_file:
      - environment

  router:
    image: apache/druid:29.0.1
    container_name: router
    volumes:
      - router_var:/opt/druid/var
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - postgres
      - coordinator
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    command:
      - router
    env_file:
      - environment


Anyone got the solution for the above question ?

I'd suggest tagging this with docker versus Druid, since the issue here is with how to bind a path so that the container can access the files. Druid, like any other app, is just going to use whatever environment you provide to it - and in this instance, the containers just need a place to get your data from.

(When playing around with Druid, btw, I usually end up spinning up Min.io cos that gives you a cool S3 to play with locally - and it's closer to what you'd use in prod anyway... you can also check out https://github.com/implydata/learn-druid which has a nice env you can play with)

In my case simply create some file environment without any format, I use nano to create file
nano environment

